# List combined size of all files with type in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm new to batch scripts and I wanted to know if it's possible to list the combined size of all files with type in a text file.

For example: if there are two `.mp3` files each of `1GB` the output should be

```
MP3 2147483648 bytes
```

I know how to list all files in a directory or just list files of one type. The problem I have is adding the sizes of of similar file types together.

Here's my code so far:

```
@echo off

Rem This is for listing down all the files in the directory Program files 

set mypath=%cd%

dir "%mypath%" *.mp3 > %mypath%\lists.txt 
echo program completed
```

Comment: The question implies that you want a list which shows each file type in a directory along side the total size in bytes for that particular file type. Your code example however, shows only one file type and makes no attempt at producing information similar to your output example. This isn't a code request service, we're happy to help you with your code, but in order to do so it is expected that the code you provide makes an attempt at the task you require help with.

Comment: CMD.exe is limited to 32 bit integers.  So you can only add up to 2,147,483,647 bytes.  Or essentially 2 Gigabytes.  So this is not a good task for batch files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple to adjust the Batch code in order to manage *any number of digits* in the result. This solution allows to manage up to 16 digits in the accumulated results:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "digits=8"

rem Assemble the factor with the proper number of digits
set "factor=1"
for /L %%i in (1,1,%digits%) do set "factor=!factor!0"

rem Accumulate size of all extensions in 2 groups of %digits% digits each
for %%a in (*.*) do (
   set "size=%factor%%%~Za"
   set /A "low[%%~Xa]+=1!size:~-%digits%!-factor, carry=low[%%~Xa]/factor, low[%%~Xa]%%=factor"
   set "size=%%~Za"
   set "size=!size:~0,-%digits%!"
   set /A "high[%%~Xa]+=carry+size"
)

rem Show results
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[.]=" %%a in ('set high[') do (
   if %%b neq 0 (
      set "low=%factor%!low[.%%a]!"
      echo %%a %%b!low:~-%digits%! bytes
   ) else (
      echo %%a !low[.%%a]! bytes
   )
)
```

Output example:

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\tests> dir *.mp3
 El volumen de la unidad C no tiene etiqueta.
 El número de serie del volumen es: 0895-160E

 Directorio de C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\tests

07/07/2010  09:58 a. m.        14,336,418 BigFile.mp3
01/05/2018  03:01 p. m.       143,364,180 BigFile2.mp3
01/05/2018  03:13 p. m.     1,433,641,800 BigFile3.mp3
07/07/2010  09:58 a. m.        14,336,418 BigFileB.mp3
               4 archivos  1,605,678,816 bytes
               0 dirs  390,478,827,520 bytes libres

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\tests> test.bat
bat 200759 bytes
csv 20412 bytes
mp3 1605678816 bytes
pdf 62799 bytes
txt 1036041 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks alot this really helps.

Comment: May I ask you to select the green check mark of this answer?

Comment: Although what part do i need to change to change the target directory for input and output? I though replacing the *.* with %cd% but that just broke it :/.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that this task is less than simple for somebody new to batch scripting and will offer a solution which leverages `PowerShell` instead.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "MyDir=%~1"
If Defined MyDir CD /D "%MyDir%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
Dir /B/A-D >Nul 2>&1 || Exit /B
(For /F "Skip=3 Tokens=1-2 Delims=. " %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP -NoL^
 "GCI -Ex 'lists.txt' -Fo|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|Group Extension|"^
 "Select Name,@{n='TS';e={(($_.Group|Measure Length -Sum).Sum)}}"
') Do Echo %%A %%B bytes)>"%__CD__%lists.txt"
```

With this you'd either:

- replace `%~1` with your target directory.
  *(do not touch the doublequotes)*

or:

- send your target directory as an argument to the script.

If neither are done, it should produce output for the current directory.

*(Please note that because the output file overwrites any existing one in the target directory it would include an old size of itself in its own results. For this reason I have added an exclusion, (untested), as part of the `PowerShell` commands)*

Comment: Is powerShell so much simpler or why are you offering it as a batch alternative? Also thanks for the solution.

Comment: @LuigiKraken, because your question specifically uses a batch file and is tagged as such, I provided a solution which matches your request! _If a solution achieves the intended goal, you should consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the check mark to the left of your chosen answer._

Answer (score 0):

As long as the cumulated size doesn't exceed the integer limit (2,147,483,647),
this small batch might do:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\01\SO_50117738.cmd
@Echo off & SetLocal
Pushd "C:\Test"
For /f "delims==" %%A in ('2^>Nul Set Ext[') Do Set "%%A="
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/A-D') Do Set /A "Ext[%%~xA]+=%%~zA/1024"
Set Ext[
```

Sample output now for whole kbytes (bytes truncated)

```
> Q:\Test\2018\05\01\SO_50117738.cmd
Ext[.cmd]=0
Ext[.html]=2
Ext[.ps1]=11
Ext[.sh]=3
Ext[.txt]=3
Ext[.vbs]=0
Ext[]=0
```

---

```
> powershell -nop -nol "$ext=@{};ls -File|%{$ext.\"$($_.Extension)\"+=$_.Length};$ext"

Name                           Value
----                           -----
.txt                           4567
.ps1                           12827
.vbs                           435
.cmd                           2000
.sh                            4605
.html                          3536
                               219
```

Another one with a bit more control over the output

```
> powershell -nop -nol "$ext=@{};ls -File|%{$ext.\"$($_.Extension)\"+=$_.Length};$ext.GetEnumerator()|sort Name|%{'{0,-6} {1,12}' -f $_.Name,$_.Value}"
                219
.cmd           2000
.html          3536
.ps1          12827
.sh            4605
.txt           4567
.vbs            435
```

Comment: Had the question not started with a simple two file example already at or exceeding the limit, I fear it is not a solution in this case, _(which is a shame due to its simplicity)_. It would be nicer were you to try to better replicate the required output, should those limits no longer be an issue, or for future searches.

Comment: I know there are a few pure batch files out there that help exceed the 32bit Integer limit.  But of course that makes your code much longer.  I was using some of Judago's scripts but his website no longer exists.  I have not seen him post on StackOverFlow or DosTips.com in several years.

Comment: Well a 1GB mp3 file is quite unlikely, but you are right - I'll change it to count kbytes and add a powershell variant of the same algorythm with a hashtable.