# Parent directory batch

Tags: batch-file, directory, parent

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50117738) of mine, [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560) provided me with this code:

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "digits=8"
set mypath=%~dp0
cd /d "%~dp0"

rem delete old list from current even if read only
del /f list.txt

rem Assemble the factor with the proper number of digits
set "factor=1"
for /L %%i in (1,1,%digits%) do set "factor=!factor!0"

rem Accumulate size of all extensions in 2 groups of %digits% digits each
for %%a in (*.*) do (
   set "size=%factor%%%~Za"
   set /A "low[%%~Xa]+=1!size:~-%digits%!-factor, carry=low[%%~Xa]/factor, 
low[%%~Xa]%%=factor"
   set "size=%%~Za"
   set "size=!size:~0,-%digits%!"
   set /A "high[%%~Xa]+=carry+size"
)

rem Show results
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[.]=" %%a in ('set high[') do (
   if %%b neq 0 (
      set "low=%factor%!low[.%%a]!"
      echo %%a %%b!low:~-%digits%! bytes >>"%mypath%\list.txt"
   ) else (
      echo %%a !low[.%%a]! bytes >>"%mypath%\list.txt"
   )
)
```

Now I'm trying to make it search through the parent directory when creating the list.

*I still want the final test file to be saved to the local directory, so no changes there!*

Comment: What about `cd /d "%~dp0.."` then?

Comment: Im new to batch so im not quite sure what you mean.. if you meant to say i should replace " cd /d "%~dp0"" with "cd /d "%~dp0.."" that did not work.

Comment: Well the del command also needs a path, but otherwise you asked for the parent dir - and that's what `cd /d "%~dp0.."` does. As the `for %%a in (*.*) do (` iterates the current dir you then do the same one level up.

Comment: As already stated, `cd /d "%~dp0.."` and `del /f "%~dp0list.txt"` are the changes you need to make. You should optionally remove the unnecessary `set mypath=%~dp0` and change both instances of `"%mypath%\list.txt"` to `"%~dp0list.txt"` or leave it in and change them to `"%mypath%list.txt"`. Also, had you instead used [the code I provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50120329) in the linked question, there were basic instructions for passing your directory to it, _(you could have just dragged and dropped your parent directory onto it)!_